# Django rest framework model viewset extra action responding always "Not found" error

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

why does setting customize actions for the model view set is not working well?
from topbar.models import TopBar

this is the relevant part in viewset code:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.exceptions import NotAcceptable
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import action

from topbar.serializers import TopBarSerializer


class TopBarSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    API endpoint from top bar content
    """
    queryset = TopBar.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TopBarSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put']
    
    @action(detail=True, methods=['get'])
    def set_topbar(self, request):
        return Response({'status': 'topbar set'})
```

I'm using routing exactly like the documentation:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'topbar', TopBarSet, basename='topbar')
```

Comment: What was the URL that you have tried?

Comment: This path working (viewset path) - /topbar/
this path not working (what I'm trying to create now) - /topbar/set_topbar/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have set **`detail=True`** in the route hence DRF will create a ***detail view route*** for you and it needs an *identifier* like a *primary key*.

So, set **`detail=False`**

```
class TopBarSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = TopBar.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TopBarSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated]
    http_method_names = ['get', 'post', 'put']

    @action(detail=False, methods=['get'])
    def set_topbar(self, request):
        return Response({'status': 'topbar set'})
```

Now, try the URL ***`topbar/set_topbar/`*** to access the custom route.